# Speed up tikz externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, externalize

I am using the `externalize` functionality of `tikz` for a large document with many complicated pictures.
Whenever `tikz` has to generate a single picture because I have changed its code it executes the code of all pictures.
Basically `externalize` works only well when no pictures need to be generated, then the document compiles very fast.
Even when only a trivial picture needs to be regenerated the compilation give me enough time to make a coffee.

I have tried to understand the `mode` setting and the option `graphics if exists` seems to be very close to what I am looking for, but it does only typeset the picture without saving it.
Is there a way to include all previously generated pictures when generating a new one so that their code is not executed?

Comment: Instead of externalize you could simply create a separate standalone for each picture an only recompile the ones that need it.

Comment: That is of course true, but the costs are also high in this case, as I would loose a lot of convenience features like automatic size adjustment via `\textwidth`.

Comment: There are ways to trasfer information across files, although the easiest is print `\the\textwidth` and use `\setlength{\textwidth}{245pt}` or whatever in the standalone.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is not the default unless you insert a new picture early in the document, which will cause all later pictures to also be recompiled. If you simply change the code of any picture, only that picture is recompiled. If you're seeing something else, it is due to code you've not shown.